# Como solucionar o limite 53 categorias do randomForest do R?

Tags: r, randomforest

No R, utilizando a library `randomForest`, quando executo `randomForest()` recebo a seguente mensagem de erro:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

O fator em questão tem 57 categorias. Como posso mudar este limite ou contornar este problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, se pergunte se é mesmo necessário ter uma variável categórica com esta quantidade de níveis. Ao fazer a divisão de um fator de n níveis, o random forest realiza 2^n-2 divisões possíveis desta variável para escolher o melhor ponto de divisão. Neste caso, são 9.00719925e15 resultados possíveis.

Se teu computador conseguir levar 0.001 segundo para fazer cada divisão dessa, ele vai levar 285616 anos para finalizar a modelagem. Isso é mais tempo que nós, humanos, existimos como espécie na Terra.

Em primeiro lugar, eu me perguntaria porque esta variável tem tantos níveis assim.

1. Ela seria uma variável numérica que foi lida incorretamente? Neste caso, trate-a como números e não categorias.
2. Caso a variável seja categórica, é possível tratá-la como variável ordinal? Se for, o random forest consegue ser mais rápido para classificar variáveis ordinais do que nominais.
3. Caso a variável seja categórica nominal, é possível simplificá-la em menos categorias? Por exemplo, caso sejam países do mundo, é possível criar uma nova variável chamada continente que vai ter apenas 6 níveis?
4. Caso a variável seja categórica nominal, é possível simplificá-la em menos categorias? Todos os níveis são representativos? Seria possível combinar os níveis de menor frequência em um novo nível chamado Outros?

Estas são algumas das que sei que são padrão num problema como esse. Não vai ser possível ajustar este modelo sem transformar esta variável em algo mais simples.

Comment: Já estou trabalhando numa forma de simplifica-la, o problema maior é que num `lm()` o R^2 aumenta em 0.35 com a adição dela. Fiquei tentado em simplesmente aplicar `as.numeric()` neste fator.